# Calling external js file and reading pure string response

Tags: karate

Since this framework is used across numerous industries, I wonder if anyone else has come across this or a similar issue.

We are looking to implement an encryption for our cc processing, but appear to be a little stuck.

While we can call the js successfully, as an external file, we are unable to easily extract the clear text response:

```
  Scenario:
    Given url 'https://safetechpageencryptionvar.chasepaymentech.com/pie/v1/**RemovedCustomerKey**/getkey.js'
            * header Accept = 'application/json'
    When method GET
    Then status 200
        * def ccEncryptedValues = response
        * print ("ccEncryptedValues are " + ccEncryptedValues)          
        * print ("responseType is " + responseType) 

14:54:16.899 [com.intuit.karate.Main.main()] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] ccEncryptedValues are //----------------------------------------------------------------------
// (c) Copyright 2018 Micro Focus or one of its affiliates.
// The only warranties for products and services of Micro Focus and its affiliates and licensors ("Micro Focus") are set forth in the express warranty statements accompanying such products and services. Nothing herein should be construed as constituting an additional warranty. Micro Focus shall not be liable for technical or editorial errors or omissions contained herein. The information contained herein is subject to change without notice.
//----------------------------------------------------------------------

// PIE version: 1.2.1

var PIE = {};  // PIE namespace

// dynamically-generated PIE settings
PIE.L = 6;
PIE.E = 4;
PIE.K = "1D247ABE7E61925D37F448B8AB74C424";
PIE.key_id = "f3425510";
PIE.phase = 1; 
14:54:16.901 [com.intuit.karate.Main.main()] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] responseType is string
```

Without splitting the text response into separate lines, loop over each line to find the relevant PIE.<> values, and then evaluate the values to be extracted (length + with or without "'s), is there a simplier way to do this?  This data is then passed to a separate js file along with the cc info, to actually complete the encryption.

We also have an html file, which does these actions at the click of a button, but this is not published internally or publically (just a floating file).  I tried to add this file to karate structure, but when trying to call the html file, I received the following errors:

```
    Scenario:
    Given url 'classpath:commonutilhelpers/CC_encryption/cardtester.html'
            * header Accept = 'application/json'
    When method GET
    Then status 200
        * def ccEncryptedValues = response

http call failed after 45 milliseconds for url: classpath:commonutilhelpers/CC_encryption/cardtester.html
org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException: URI does not specify a valid host name: classpath:commonutilhelpers/CC_encryption/cardtester.html
src/test/java/adapters/ccEncrypt.feature:31
```

or

```
    Scenario:
    * def someFunction = read('classpath:commonutilhelpers/CC_encryption/cardtester.html')
    * def ccEncryptedValues = call someFunction
            * print ('ccEncryptedValues are ', ccEncryptedValues) 

15:22:49.275 [com.intuit.karate.Main.main()] ERROR com.intuit.karate - src/test/java/adapters/ccEncrypt.feature:36
* def ccEncryptedValues = call someFunction
not a callable feature or js function: [type: BYTES, value: [B@20552b87]
```

NOTE: I can add the html if desired, but unsure if that would be helpful without our, or a valid, customer key.

Comment: see if this helps: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-examples/blob/main/axe/README.md

Comment: I did not quite follow the steps of this setup as my question was how to read/parse a pure text response `While we can call the js successfully, as an external file, we are unable to easily extract the clear text response:...`  The other issue posted was accessing a local html file `We also have an html file, which does these actions at the click of a button, but this is not published internally or publically (just a floating file). I tried to add this file to karate structure, but when trying to call the html file, I received the following errors:`.